# Cannot change java version on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows

I have jdk6 and jdk7 installed on my Windows 8 machine. The JAVA_HOME environment variable originally pointed to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7.

I am now trying to run a program under Java 1.6. I changed JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jre6 but when I type java -version at the command prompt I get "java version "1.7.0_25". I have even deleted all environment variables related to Java and modified the path variable to not include any reference to Java. However, when I type java -version (which should fail) I get "java version "1.7.0_25".

I have also tried changing JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45" and java -versio still gives me "java version "1.7.0_25".

Does anyone know why I am unable to change the Java version to 1.6?

My current path is:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;%OPEN_SSL%\bin
```

Comment: did you close and re-open the command prompt between changing the values?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on http://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried a restart and a hard shutdown and reboot.

Comment: You should also ensure that `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is in your `PATH` before any other Java bin folder.

Comment: @meyerjp3 - is there a java.exe in system32 ? try renaming it out of the way or placing java on the path before system32, or maybe paste the definition pf PATH on your machine here

Comment: You could also use `where java` to locate any unwanted java binary in your path.

Comment: @meyerjp3 Try to put `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` before `%SystemRoot%\system32`

Comment: Ah ha, `where java` revealed that there is a java.exe in C:\windows\System32 and it is listed before the jdk1.6 path. Does that file need to be in system32? Is there a good way to avoid this?

Comment: @meyerjp3 The `java.exe` in `system32` is a *dummy* implementation that look at the registry for the last installed JVM and used its implementation.

Comment: Thanks @radai, that fixed the problem. I listed JAVA_HOME before %SystemRoot%\System32 and `java -version` now correctly returns "java version "1.6.0_45"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `JAVA_HOME` variable before `%SystemRoot%\system32` one. Windows installer adds java.exe file to Windows\system32 directory. And since it comes before JAVA_HOME, the executable from system32 is used.

(don't forget to restart console before checking again for java version)

Edit: last java adds to PATH folder `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`. in my case it was on first position in PATH. That folder contains symlinks to java.exe javaw.exe and javaws.exe. Now you have two options.

- you can delete `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and add `JAVA_HOME` (or point directly do java bin directory
- you can change symlinks in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` to those pointing to right executables.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the right JVM called from the terminal when you call `java` directly, you'll have to put `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` in your path before any other directory that may contain a `java.exe` implementation.

If you have installed a JVM using the Java installer, you may have a `java.exe` in your `%SystemRoot%\system32`. This one is just a dummy implementation that look at the registry and use the last JVM installed.

If you have a `java.exe` in your `%SystemRoot%\system32` and it's not using the right JVM, you'll either have to correctly uninstall all JVM or to put `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` before `%SystemRoot%\system32` in your path.